# Spring Data Mongo DB: The reply message length 5502322 is less than the maximum message length

Tags: mongodb, azure, spring-data-mongodb

Code:

Interface::

```
@Query(value = "{'status': {$in: ?0} , 'date':{ $lte: ?1 }}")
List<Blog> findByStatusAndCurrentDateWithOrdering(List<String> status, Date date, Sort order);
```

Calling Class:

```java
findByStatusAndCurrentDateWithOrdering(status, new Date(), Sort.by(Direction.DESC, "date")
```

Error from Application deployed in Azure:

```
"status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "The reply message length 5502322 is less than the maximum message length 4194304; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoIn
ternalException: The reply message length 5502322 is less than the maximum message length 4194304",
```

The content in MongoDB includes Base64 Image as well as ID, HTML. (and only have 11 or 12 rows)

The Azure Mongo DB version of customer is < 3.2.0. Whereas at local it is > 3.2

What changes could be done in above code to read it in chunks or limit to get it work?

Comment: It is a sort issue. You need to change you MongoRepository method to Aggregation query

Answer (score 1):

You need to change to this:

```
db.blog.aggregate([
    {$match:{"status": {$in: status} , "date":{ $lte: date }}},
    {$sort:{"date":-1}}
],{allowDiskUse:true})
```

**Edit:**

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;
...

//Inside your `@Service` class, include:
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongotemplate;
...

MatchOperation filter = match(Criteria.where("status").in(status).and("date").lte(date));
SortOperation sort    = sort(Direction.DESC, "date")

Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(filter, sort)
                             .withOptions(newAggregationOptions()
                             .allowDiskUse(true).build());
AggregationResults<Blog> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollection(Blog.class), Blog.class);
List<Blog> blogs = result.getMappedResults();
```

Comment: But how to do this in spring datajpa? Because when i run simple find query in mongo db console, it returns results without any issues.

Comment: @fatherazrael I've updated my answer, please take a look

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I will test and get back to you by tomorrow evening.